# Excel error charts and drawings

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-365

I'm experiencing an odd issue with Excel. Whenever I open an Excel file (both xlsm or xlsx, Office 365) I receive back an error message about drawings and I cannot see any chart or drawing inside, even if they are there since I did them. If I open the file from another PC/user, it works fine so it seems to be a problem related to my user or Excel version or whatever. Below are some screenshots. 
They are in Spanish so you can see a brief English description.

[image: 1st message: content issue]

When I decide to repair it, Excel generates a report (xml) but it doesn't help.

[image: 2nd message, after "repairing" the file as requested on the previous message]

Apart from this, whenever I try to create a new chart (no matter the file extension) I see this message and it's not possible at all to do anything else.

[image: Error trying to create a new chart]
I've been thinking about possible changes I could have made and I've installed the trial version of Power BI a couple of week ago but the issue started about one week ago so I don't think it's related and I don't see any other connection with any other action I could have taken.

I would like to avoid the uninstall/reinstall option so, does anybody have an idea or a solution in order to fix this?

Comment: What is the version of Excel where it works and what is the version of excel where it does not?  Are all the same VBA libraries (library may not be the right term) active on both computers

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I didn't mention it but it's exactly the same Excel version and the same VBA reference libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution, it's in Spanish but I hope many of you can use it.
To be honest, I did reinstall Office so I cannot confirm this would work. 
By the way, here you have the link: [Link](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/excel-2016-no-puede-abrir-archivos-que-contengan-gr%C3%A1ficos-o-insertar-nuevos-gr%C3%A1ficos-d01c197f-0269-4a0d-8b8e-569021730662)
Basically, they give 2 options:

1) Change the region of operating systems and the regional format briefly to a different configuration. Then return to the original configuration

2) Install the English language pack